# JavaScript function: what does this do?

Tags: javascript, function

I have been looking at this code for sometime now, trying to understand what it does but I can't really get my head around it. I need help with understanding what this function actually does

```
function element(array, gen) {
if(gen === undefined) {
    gen = fromTo(
        0,
        array.length
    );
}
return function() {
    var index = gen();
    if(index !== undefined) {
        return array[index];
    }
};
```

}

```
function concat(...gens) {
    var next = element(gens),
    gen = next();
    return function recur() {
        var value = gen();
        if(value === undefined) {
            gen = next();
            if(gen !== undefined) {
                return recur();
            }
        }
        return value;
    };
}
```

Comment: What does `element` do? It's not defined in your sample code.

Comment: What parts(s) do you not understand?

Comment: @djfdev it's not significant. Telling by the rest of the code, it's a function with the signature *(Typescript)* `element<T,U>(args: T[]) => () => (() => U | void) | void;` and we don't care about the types of `T` and `U` because nothing else in this code cares.

Comment: @Atoms, you can rewrite this as `function concat(...gens) { var next = element(gens), gen; return function(){ while(gen = next()){ var value = gen(); if(value !== undefined) return value; }}`

Comment: Foolish me. I don't even know how to ask a question properly. I have edited the code to carry the element function

Answer (score 0):

`element` is not a javascript built-in which means it must be defined elsewhere. Without knowing its function, it is impossible to say exactly what is happening, but here is what I can tell you.

`concat` takes n arguments of the same type. Without knowing what `element` does I can't tell you what type that is, but it can take as many as you need to give it. That is what the spread operator `...` is telling you.

It returns a function that takes 0 arguments. When called, it continues to call itself checking if the return value of `gen()` is defined, if it is not, it changes gen to be the return value of `next()` and calls `gen()` again. It repeats this process until the return value of `gen()` is defined, and then returns that value.

Using it would look something like this.

```js
var recur = concat(a,b,c,d,e); // can take any number of arguments of the same type
var someValue = recur(); // calls itself until it has a value to return
console.log(someValue); // use the value
```

Comment: so how can you answer it not knowing it? ;)

Comment: because I understand the basics of recursive functions and javascript operations. Just because I can't tell you exactly what it's doing doesn't mean I can't tell you about its recursive nature. The OP was vauge; I provided the best answer I could under the circumstances. Might still be helpful for others stumbling across similar looking functions.

Comment: I have edited the code to carry the element function. Can you please update your answer for a better understanding